# Intellij CVS SSH error "Valid requests expected!"

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, cvs

I am attempting to get version control working on my Intellij project. I have a server sitting at home which I will be conntecting to via backhand meaning the CVS commiting will only work locally but that is all i need. In CVS settings I have made my root as follow:

:ssh:taka@192.168.1.7:22/Repository

Which gives the error "Valid requests expected!"

To fix this I have tried to change it to:

:ssh:taka:mypassword@192.168.1.7:22/Repository

and even

:ssh:taka:mypassword@192.168.1.7:22/home/taka/Repository

but both do not work, am I missing something that I should have done ? any help please ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unless IntelliJ is weird, this would be incorrect :ext: syntax. A colon usually separates the server and repository path. I.e. :ext:taka@192.168.1.7:/path/to/Repository

Answer (score -2):

A quick google says to use `:ext:` not `:ssh:`.

Try this `:ext:taka@192.168.1.7:/Repository`.

Comment: Unless IntelliJ is weird, this would be incorrect :ext: syntax.  A colon usually separates the server and repository path.  I.e. :ext:taka@192.168.1.7:/path/to/Repository